# Update database daily with cronjobs (Mysql, Mongodb)

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, laravel, database

I want to create a web site with laravel based on a database (Mysql or Mongodb) that has almost 500.000 records. The main problem so far is that i want to update the database records daily with cronjobs. What is the best database solution to use in order to have a good flow on the updates. The tables of the database are not many and there are not really relashionships on the records. Can you advise me which database to choose? Mysql or Mongodb? Is it possible to host that web site on a sharing hosting? or do i need to move to a dedicated server. As i say before the records are 500.000 and they will be adding (new), deleting (trash) and updating (existing) around 5% of the records daily.

Comment: You could also look at [Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/). An excellent database server.

Answer (score 1):

1. MySQL or MongoDB: we can't answer without knowing how the data are structured and what usage you are planning. If you require relations and cross-references between records OR if data consistency is vital to your application, then go with MySQL. Otherwise, if data are not related and rapidity is most important then ensured data consistency, MongoDB is the choice
2. Yes, you can host it in a shared hosting service

25k records to elaborate in a whole day requires low computational resource, it should not be a big problem

I just want to advice you to keep in consideration further development of your application: are you completely sure that records will always be around 500k and they will not increase to millions or even more?

Comment: thank you for you answer :) The records of the database are products with 6-7 seven fields. (title, description, price, link, image, size...). I just want the visitor to be able to view the products in the frontend. No shopping cart fuctonality at all, no payments. just showing the data from the database to the visitors.
Yes, there is a possibilty for the records to increase in 1.000.000 but not in the very near future. i mean maybe the records throught the daily update will increase to thsi number someday after 1 year or so.

Comment: If you only need 1 table for products, then probably mongoDB is the best solution because it is really fast.